# A problem occurred configuring project ':pdf_render'

Tags: flutter, pdf-render

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':pdf_render'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: NDK at D:\Resources\AndroidStudioSDK\ndk\21.4.7075529 did not have a source.properties file

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

```
pdf_render: ^1.0.12
```

I'm getting error related to ndk source.properties.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution:

The error occurs because of incomplete download of NDK hence the source.properties is missing.

**Solution: go to the ndk directory and delete the corresponding folder**

In my case the path was `D:\Resources\AndroidStudioSDK\ndk\21.4.7075529`, I deleted the folder `21.4.7075529`. You can find the ndk folder path in the error message itself.

After deleting the folder execute the app, the ndk fresh download will start again.

Let it complete and the problem is solved !!!